# Customize form field rendering

Tags: forms, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I would like to customize the rendering of a form field in the edit page from  [sonata admin bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html) to include an applet that uses the text content of a field.

I know that I have to edit the `configureFormFields` function in the admin class, but I need to know 3 things:

- What is the syntax to provide a field form template
- Where to put the template file ( which directory )
- What the template have to looks like.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution

What i have done is:

1. Created a field type, lets call it *myfieldType* in myCompany\myBundle\Form\Type\myfieldType.php

   ```
   namespace myCompany\myBundle\Form\Type;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

   class myfieldType extends AbstractType
   {

       public function getParent()
       {
           return 'text';
       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return 'myfield';
       }
   }
   ```
2. Registered the Type in app/config/services.yml

   ```
   myCompany.myBundle.form.type.myfield:
       class: myCompany\myBundle\Form\Type\myfieldType
       tags:
           - { name: form.type, alias: myfield }
   ```
3. In my myentityAdmin class,

   ```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
        ->add('myfieldname', 'myfield')
        ...
    }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public function getFormTheme() {
       return array('myCompanymyBundle:Admin:myfield_edit.html.twig');
   }
   ```

   and the template :

   ```
   {# src/mycompany/myBundle/Resources/views/Form/myfield_edit.html.twig #}
   {% block myfield_widget %}
       {% spaceless %}
           {{ block('textarea_widget') }}
       {% endspaceless %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```

And now i can access the form field value by the twig variable "value" !

So easy... when you got it.

Comment: Didn't work on Sonata 3.1: "Neither the property "myfieldname" nor one of the methods "getMyfieldname()", "myfieldname()", "isMyfieldname()", "hasMyfieldname()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class..."

Comment: The date of the anwser is 2013, so the version was like SonataAdminBundle 2.xx ...

Comment: Yes, i was just stating that fact. For the ones using Sonata 3+ and SF 2.8+, it has changed: you must drop the `getName()` method; you can ignore the `alias` in the service declaration; you use directly the class name (and not the alias) in the `$formMapper->add()` method (2nd argument)

Answer (score 8):

user1254498's solution won't work unless the block name prefix matches the name of the form type. At least with the last version of sonata admin bundle (2.2.12). In this case:

```
{# src/mycompany/myBundle/Resources/views/Form/myfield_edit.html.twig #}
{% block myfield_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {{ block('textarea_widget') }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

And, regarding `getFormTheme()`, you shoud return also the parent theme, otherwise you may break the whole style...

```
public function getFormTheme()
{
    return array_merge(
            parent::getFormTheme(), array(
          'mycompanyBundle:Form:myfield_edit.html.twig')
    );        
}
```

Also, you can access the admin service in the twig template with the variable `sonata_admin.admim`.

Answer (score 5):

In your services.yml file you define the template for your edit Action:

```
app.admin.product:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\ProductAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Product, AppBundle:Admin\Product]
    tags:
        - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Products, label: Products}
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, [edit, AppBundle:Product:edit.html.twig]]
```

In that template you can then override templates for fields in your form:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form.selectall 'AppBundle:Form:selectall.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form.Country 'AppBundle:Form:country.html.twig' %}
```

Then my template looks like that:

```
{% block form_row %}
<div class="form-group">
{{ form_label(form) }}
{% set c = 0 %}
{% for i in form %}
    {% set c = c+1 %}
    {% if (c == 1) %}
        <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
    {% endif%}
    {{ form_row(i) }}
    {% if ((c == 60) or (form|length == loop.index)) %}
        </div>
        {% set c = 0 %}
    {% endif%}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

In this case, my countries check boxes appear in column of 60 elements, not in one column with the whole list of elements.

Hope this is helpful to someone else.