# issue loading js code when Customizing form field symfony/ sonata Admin

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, sonata-admin

i'm trying to customise a field  of a form generated with sonata admin bundle, i adopted the solution posted here: [Customize form field rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194148/customize-form-field-rendering)
what i want to do also is to execute an autocomplete script with ajax that load for me possible values for the field i've already created, so iwrote the script in the myfield_edit.html.twig mentionned in the solution.
My problem: when loading the form page, my script's never been loaded! 
help pleaze!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry finally i convinced my boss to update everything for better use of any package in the future.
now the pain is gone.
thank you all for help.

Comment: This should be a comment (if you have privileges to do it), not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try things as seen on this page : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html

(see SONATA_TYPE_MODEL_AUTOCOMPLETE)

Comment: very useful but i forgot to mention that i'm running an old version of sonata that can't recognise the SONATA_TYPE_MODEL_AUTOCOMPLETE formType, right know i can't update the sonata package

Comment: may be some of my app funcionnalities won't work.That's why, i'm working with symfony 2.0
It's an old project.my boss won't update it

Comment: what is your field type !! i think sonata user select2 with implement the auto complete functionality

Comment: It comes directly from the Sonata doc