# How to customize particular field rendering in SonataAdmin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In my `Admin` class, inside `configureFormFields` method I have checkbox field `excerptImageSide`:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
     $formMapper
      // ...
         ->add('excerptImageSide')
     ;
}
```

Now in admin create/edit page checkbox is rendered like:

[image]

As you see checkbox is under label, but I would like to have it on single line. So my question is how to apply custom template for particular field rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way I know is to wrap the field in a `->with(...)` that have a class, and make some custom CSS:

**Admin**

```
 $formMapper
  // ...
     ->with('YourSection', array('class' => 'floating-checkboxes'))
         ->add('excerptImageSide')
     ->end()
 ;
```

**CSS**

```
.floating-checkboxes label{
    float: left;      // Make the label floating
    min-width: 185px; // Keep a correct space between the field and its label
}
```

To load your custom stylesheet, or make a complete override of the field template, look at the [advanced configuration documentation chapter](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply! That is really working solution. Do I correctly understand, that in order to override original template of form  I need extend `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig` ?

Comment: You should look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194148/customize-form-field-rendering . But override a complete field for adding a few lines of html/css seems overkill for me, it's at your own appreciation :) .