# Sonata Admin - How to add a link to a field

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a field on my form in Sonata Admin:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('filePath', TextType::class, [
            'disabled' => true,
        ]);
}

protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('filePath');
}
```

This relates to an entity which stores the path of a file.

```
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $filePath;
```

How can I update the form so that I am able to click on the field so that it opens the file in another tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a template inside `configureShowFields` for the `filePath` field, here is a sample for your case:

```php
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('filePath', null, [
            'template' => '@App/Admin/file_path_link.html.twig',
        ]);
}
```

And the `@App/Admin/file_path_link.html.twig`:

```
{% if value %}
<a href="{{ value }}">click to download</a>
{% else %}
No file path
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for configureShowFields. But if I try this on configureFormFields I get the error - The option "template" does not exist.

Comment: A little bit difficult for the formField, here you can find how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194148/customize-form-field-rendering